# I am a newbie to android development and I am having some problems

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just started learning android studio and I am facing some rendering problems. When I place a button or an image, it shows this error and don't run on an emulator.
Below is a screenshot of that error..
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joBPJ.png)
XML code...

```
<Button
    android:text="Click Me"
    android:layout_width="143dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.88" />
```

Comment: please post your xml layout to help better

Comment: I posted the XML code.

Comment: Wow , that's lot of attributes  :) ,which layout for this button did  you use ?
please post all xml code of your layout

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild your project. Build > Rebuild Project in the top bar.

Comment: I did rubild. It's not helping. Same erroe again